# Failed to generalize some common codes for TableColumn of JavaFX

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, javafx, types

In [this example for TableView of JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/TableViewSample.java.html), the 3 instances of `TableColumn` are doing mostly the same thing. Thus I would like to write a new class `SuperColumn extends TableColumn` to handle the routine process of `TableColumn`. Therefore I tried to put the common codes at the constructor as below:

```
public class SuperColumn<Person, V> extends TableColumn<Person, V>{
    String columnHead;
    int columnWidth;
    String variableName;

    public SuperColumn(String columnHead, int columnWidth, String variableName) {
        super();
        this.setText(columnHead);
        this.setMinWidth(columnWidth);      
        this.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, V>(variableName));        
        this.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, V>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, V> t) {
                        ((Person) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                                ).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                });   
    }

}
```

In the above, I want `setEmail` to depend on `variableNew`. That is, if `variableNew` is `"setEmail"`, then we will call `setEmail(t.getNewValue())`. If `variableNew` is `"setFirstName"`, then we will call `setFirstName(t.getNewValue())`.

How can I achieve this?

Even just for the above code, I got error message "The method setEmail(V) is undefined for the type Person".

Comment: that example is (and always was) crap - expose the properties, then you don't need edit handlers. Anyway, basic OO mandates to __not__ extend for configuration reasons - you are in the wrong track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to combine the ideas of Lê Hoàng Dững (i.e. to use `Function<S, Property<T>>`) and James_D (i.e. to use `TableColumns.Create()`), and I got:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;

public class TableColumns<S,T> {

    public static <S, T> TableColumn<S,T> create(String columnHead, int columnWidth, Function<S, Property<T>> myFunc) {
    
        TableColumn<S, T> myColumn = new TableColumn<>(columnHead);

        myColumn.setMinWidth(columnWidth);
        myColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> myFunc.apply(cellData.getValue())); // binding column (i.e. this) and the variable
        myColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
            int row = event.getTablePosition().getRow();
            S rowValue = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            T newValue = event.getNewValue();
            myFunc.apply(rowValue).setValue(newValue);
        });
        return myColumn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in terms of general programming style, it's not particularly good practice to subclass a class solely for the purpose of configuring the instances that are created, unless you are providing additional functionality that isn't provided by the base class. If the subclass does nothing other than have a constructor, this is a particular indicator of this anti-pattern. A better approach, which I'll show here, is to use some kind of creational pattern, which may be as simple as some static methods that create instances for you. (More advanced implementations would use various factory patterns.)

Anyway, a version of what you're trying to do, which doesn't rely on reflection (I'll explain later why I don't like the reflective approach) would need you to pass in some kind of function which processes the new (edited) value for a particular `Person` instance.  A [`BiConsumer<Person, V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) works well for this:

```
public class TableColumns {
    public static <V> TableColumn<Person,V> create(String columnHead, int columnWidth, String variableName, BiConsumer<Person, V> setter) {
        TableColumn<Person, V> column = new TableColumn<>(columnHead);
        column.setMinWidth(columnWidth);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(variableName));
        column.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
            int row = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
            Person person = t.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            V value = t.getNewValue();
            setter.consume(person, value);
        });
        return column ;
    }

}
```

which you would create with

```
TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn = 
    TableColumns.create("Email", 100, "email", Person::setEmail)
```

Note that the example you linked isn't a particularly good one (even though it's the "official" one from Oracle: it's really very old). A model class (`Person`) which uses JavaFX properties should really provide "property accessor" methods:

```
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email ;
    }

    public final String getEmail() {
        return emailProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setEmail(String email) {
        emailProperty().set(email);
    }

    // similarly for other properties

}
```

Using this version of the `Person` class, your table column simply has to access the specific property both for getting the value (in the `cellValueFactory`) and for setting the value (in the `onEditCommit` handler). So, all you need is a function which provides the property for a given `Person` instance. You can also easily generalize this to a parameterized row value of type `S`:

```
public class TableColumns {

    public static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> create(String title, int width, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> column = new TableColumn<>(title);
        column.setMinWidth(width);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        column.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
            int row = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
            S rowValue = t.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            T value = t.getNewValue();
            property.apply(rowValue).setValue(value);
        });
        return column ;
    }

    // other creational methods...
}
```

And now you do

```
TableColumn<Person, String> emailColumn = 
    TableColumns.create("Email", 100, Person::emailProperty);
```

This approach avoids both using reflection directly, and using the legacy `PropertyValueFactory` (which uses a similar reflection-based approach under the hood). The main benefit here is that the compiler will now check that the appropriate methods exist, and any errors are caught at compile time. (By contrast, when specifying the method name using reflection, or the property name in the `PropertyValueFactory`, errors cannot be caught by the compiler and it will simply fail at runtime, either silently (no data appears) or with an exception.)

Just for completeness, if you really want to use a subclass for this, it would look like

```
public class SuperColumn<S,T> extends TableColumn<S,T> {

    public SuperColumn(String title, int width, Function<S, Property<T>> property) {
        super(title);
        setMinWidth(width);
        setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        setOnEditCommit(event -> {
            int row = event.getTablePosition().getRow();
            S rowValue = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            T value = event.getNewValue();
            property.apply(rowValue).setValue(value);
        });
    }
}
```

But again, I should emphasize this is not a good use of inheritance, and you should prefer the method-based (or factory-based) approach.

Comment: would you consider to remove (or move to the end with a big no-no-dont) the extension option? full ack with the rest, so would like to upvote :)

Comment: @kleopatra Yeah, always slightly torn between answering the question as posed, or going off on something of a tangent in terms of "better design'...

Comment: @James_D, Many thanks for your reply. If I am not allowed to modify the original library that stores "TableColumns", is it still possible for me to add the `create` method? It seems that if I create a new file for `TableColumns`, I will overwrite the original definition.

Comment: @H42 I don’t understand what you mean. `TableColumns` is just the class name I chose.

Comment: @James_D, Thanks, I previously mixed up `TableColumns` and `TableColumn` and now I finally got that. But it still doesn't work when I tried your code, I got "The method consume(Person, V) is undefined for the type BiConsumer<Person,V>" (though I already added the "property accessor" methods to `Person`). Do you have any idea how to solve?

Comment: Sorry, should be `accept`, not `consume`. Will fix when I’m back at a computer

Comment: good to "hide" the subclassing approach :) Anyway, still don't quite understand the requirement (and solution): the main thingy that's done is to install a custom commit handler .. which isn't needed when exposing a property. What do I overlook?

Comment: @kleopatra As I understand it, the OP is just asking “how do I avoid code repetition “.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SuperColumn<Person, V> extends TableColumn<Person, V>{
    public SuperColumn(String columnHead, int columnWidth, String variableName) {
        super();
        this.setText(columnHead);
        this.setMinWidth(columnWidth);
        this.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(variableName));
        this.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
            int row = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
            Person person = t.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            V value = t.getNewValue();
            try {
                Method method = person.getClass().getMethod("set" + variableName, value.getClass());
                method.invoke(person, value);
            } catch ( NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

And call it:

```
SuperColumn<Person, String> column = new SuperColumn<>("Email", 100, "email");
```